# fragment supporting in lollipop is not supporting lower versions of android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-play-services

I am a beginner in android studio currently am working in an project which is imported from eclipse and i have added some new features in the project by the use of android studio.Now the problem is in fragment class the fragment which i have used in my project runs in lollipop version but it get stopped while running in lower versions of android like kitkat and jellybean.I completed checked my codings there is no wrong in that
As a beginner i don't know how to solve it.

This is the logcat of my project

Need your help friends
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi check your app compact which you supported is app compact v4 or v7 dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
} if that is v4 just add to your dependencies and sync with the gradel button

Comment: i am using app compact v7:22.0.0

Comment: in eclipse what did you support

Comment: in eclipse is support all dives

Comment: please set you min and max targets properly from api 15 to 23 and sync and re check

Comment: i  use minsdk 15,targrtsdk 21

Comment: then update you sdk of  an android studio does it updated with all the lower api if not update all and restart you studio and try

Answer (score 0):

Fragment class was introduced since api level 11. After, you have to add support-v4 library (is a jar).

When you create a MainFragment that extends Fragment, android studio can import 
check this blog. [Fragent before api 11](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments--mobile-5431)

See the doc
[fragment doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html), where you can see the different package name